# Visual Studio 2019 edit HTML file

Tags: html, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019, editor

I created a ASP.NET Core project with Visual Studio 2019 and I added a .html file. When I double click on the file, VS only opens it in edge, instead of opening it in editor. When I drag and drop the file on the editor windows, it's still the same.

How can I open html files in VS editor by default?

Edit:

It looks like a bug in Visual Studio 2019 ASP.NET Projects. It just happened there. Even new added .cs files are opened in windows 10 default text editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click your html page.Click open with.

[image]

Then you can see:

[image]

Click `HTML Editor` and `Set as Default`.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I have tried it, but it doesn't work for me (Error message: "File could not be opened. Choose another editor"). It looks like the template files for my ASP.NET core project are corrupted. When I open the file in notepad++ I can see 190 nulls. I will try to make a repair install of VS.